# Can I detect if a window is partly hidden?

Tags: delphi, visibility

Is it possible to detect if a window for a program outside mine is 1) completely visible, 2) partly hidden, or 3) completely hidden?  I want to be able to tell my application not to do anything if a window (based on a retrieved handle) isn't visible.  I don't care if the window has focus or not,what the z order is, or anything else, I'm just interested in how much of the window shows.  If I need something else to get this, I'm fine, but is it possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raymond Chen wrote [an article about this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030902-00/?p=42693) a few years ago.

The gist of it is that you can use [`GetClipBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getclipbox) to tell you what kind of clipping region a window's device context has. A null region means the window is totally obscured, and a complex region means it's partially obscured. If it's a simple (rectangular) region, then visibility depends on whether the visible rectangle coincides with the bounds of the window.

A DC can only be used by one thread at a time. Therefore, you should not acquire the DC of a window for an application that isn't yours. Otherwise, you may encounter a situation where the other application — unaware of what you're doing — attempts to use its DC while you're still using it to inspect the clipping region. It should be perfectly safe to use it to make judgments about *your own* windows, though.

Comment: Just curious: what's your source for those caveats and warnings about DC's and threads ?  I can't find anything on MSDN about that, and the fact that GetDC() has a partner ReleaseDC() [which MSDN does say must be called by the same thread that called GetDC()] suggests that thread synchronisation is (or could/should be) handled in the GDI itself... i.e. if thread A tries to GetDC(hWnd) and thread B already has it, then thread A will wait until thread B releases it.  This isn't documented, but is intuitively what I would expect.  I should add that I haven't tested this theory.

Comment: [continued]: not what I'd call "confirmation" but this question on experts-exchange does at least seem to support my theory: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Game/Game_Graphics/DirectX/Q_21986813.html

Comment: [further continued:] GetDC() can return NULL, indicating a failure to obtain a DC, so in my theoretical thread A/B scenario, it's also possible that thread A might get a NULL DC, rather than being forced to wait for thread B (depending on how the GDI does actually behave in this area).  I wonder how much code that calls GetDC() ever tests the result?  The VCL [in]famously tests the result in TWinControl.GetDeviceContext() but fails to test for the REASON for any failure and just blindly (and, in the one time I actually encountered it, incorrectly) reports an EOutOfResources.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the article you linked gives me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution I used to determine if a form is actually visible (even only partially) to the user. You can easily adapt to your exact use case.

```
function IsMyFormCovered(const MyForm: TForm): Boolean;
var
   MyRect: TRect;
   MyRgn, TempRgn: HRGN;
   RType: Integer;
   hw: HWND;
begin
  MyRect := MyForm.BoundsRect;            // screen coordinates
  MyRgn := CreateRectRgnIndirect(MyRect); // MyForm not overlapped region
  hw := GetTopWindow(0);                  // currently examined topwindow
  RType := SIMPLEREGION;                  // MyRgn type

// From topmost window downto MyForm, build the not overlapped portion of MyForm
  while (hw<>0) and (hw <> MyForm.handle) and (RType <> NULLREGION) do
  begin
    // nothing to do if hidden window
    if IsWindowVisible(hw) then
    begin
      GetWindowRect(hw, MyRect);
      TempRgn := CreateRectRgnIndirect(MyRect);// currently examined window region
      RType := CombineRgn(MyRgn, MyRgn, TempRgn, RGN_DIFF); // diff intersect
      DeleteObject( TempRgn );
    end; {if}
    if RType <> NULLREGION then // there's a remaining portion
      hw := GetNextWindow(hw, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end; {while}

  DeleteObject(MyRgn);
  Result := RType = NULLREGION;
end;

function IsMyFormVisible(const MyForm : TForm): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= MyForm.visible and
           isWindowVisible(MyForm.Handle) and
           not IsMyFormCovered(MyForm);
end;
```

Comment: This truly does work. Forget about any answer that relies on GetClipBox() - it simply does not work (at least in modern cases / Windows 10). This solution (and I had to transcode into C++) really does tell you if the window is completely hidden by covering windows. Excellent stuff.