# Function to check if a window is visible on screen does not work on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-7

For my program, I need to know if at least a pixel of a window is visible on screen.

I'm currently using this code:

```
BOOL isWindowVisible(HWND hwnd) {
    RECT r1;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r1);
    HRGN x = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&r1);

    HWND s = GetTopWindow(0);

    do {
        if (IsWindowVisible(s)) {
            RECT r2;
            GetWindowRect(s, &r2);
            HRGN y = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&r2);

            int res = CombineRgn(x, x, y, RGN_DIFF);
            DeleteObject(y);
            if (res == NULLREGION) {
                DeleteObject(x);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    } while ((s = GetNextWindow(s, GW_HWNDNEXT)) && s != hwnd);

    DeleteObject(x);
    return TRUE;
}
```

This does work on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, but not on Windows 7. On Windows 7, it returns `FALSE` every time.

I thought it is because of Aero effects, but even when I disable it, it still happens. I got this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3154853/1798024) on StackOverflow and adapted it to C++.

Does someone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out by myself. It does not check if the window on top of the z-order is the same window like the one to check. If the window is still on top, the function subtracts itself and then returns `FALSE`. I don't know why this error only happens on Windows 7, but at least it is fixed now.